# Force Sql server to use index seek in merge join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, optimization, execution-plan

I am testing Merge join in sql server. I have an `INNER JOIN` and force the optimizer to do `MERGE JOIN`:

- `ID` in Personal Table is a Primary key
- `ID` in Abteilung Table is a primary key
- There is no other Indexes in these tables

  ```
   select * from  [dbo].[Personal] as P inner join [dbo].[Abteilung] as A  
   on  P.[ID]= A.[Personal_ID]   OPTION (MERGE JOIN)
  ```

then Optimizer uses this plan to run my query:

[image]

I would like to force optimizer to use `index seek` instead of `Table Scan`

What I did to achieve this aim:

- Defining a grouped index in the Table Abteilung on columns `ID`, `Personal_ID`. If I run the query, the execution plan is changes like this:

[image]

here I have Clustered index scan, but not clustered index seek

- Using `FORCESEEK` hint. If I am using this hint, an error occures by running the query:

> Query processor could not produce a query plan because of the hints defined in this query. Resubmit the query without specifying any
>   hints and without using SET FORCEPLAN.

- If I add a where clause in the query, then the query would be change to:

  ```
    select * from  [dbo].[Personal] as P inner join [dbo].[Abteilung] as A  
    on P.[ID]= A.[Personal_ID] where A.[Personal_ID]=2 
    OPTION (MERGE    JOIN)
  ```

  [image]
  in this situation I have only Clustered index scan.

**My question:**

How do I change my query to have Clustered Index Seek in the bottom line?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? What problem are we trying to solve here?

Comment: It is only a test for me, I would like to know if it is possible ;-)

Comment: It is only an estimate but they are both 50%.  Not sure you are solving a real problem here.

Answer (score 6):

To get a clustered index seek, you'd need a clustered index that supports your filter (e.g. leading key would have to be `Personal_ID`, not `ID`).

You can't force a seek if there's no index with a leading column of `Personal_ID` that supports the filter.

This does not mean you *should* change the existing clustered index, unless this is the only query you ever run against the table.

And while you could create a non-clustered index with `Personal_ID` as the key column, a seek on that index might not be what you want anyway - since you're using `SELECT *` *(are you really sure you need all columns from both tables?)*, it will need to go fetch the rest of the columns from the clustered index anyway, and if there are more than <sub>some number of rows</sub> returned, at some point a seek (well, what would amount to a range scan disguised as a seek) + lookups will be more expensive than a regular scan.

Why do you think you need a seek here? How many rows does the query return, how wide are they, and how long does it take? Is this just educational, or are you under the assumption that a seek will always perform better than a scan? (It won't, btw.)

Some useful reading:

- [Bad habits to kick : using SELECT * / omitting the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)
- [Assumption #2 : A seek is better than a scan, always](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/t-sql-tuesday-56-sql-server-assumptions)

Comment: And even if the clustered index was changed to get a seek the plan still wouldn't have a merge join as it then just becomes a cross join of the two seeked results.

Answer (score 1):

Without having created any tests I would guess that it's not possible to seek an index without having seek predicates, especially not if you use SELECT * and get all table columns.

I would try to filter on an index-column that is part of the index you want to seek in and additionally retrieve only columns that are covered by this index.

Documentation explains that Merge join typically scans or alternatively sorts it afterwards. Read: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190967(v=sql.105).aspx